# Filter eloquent relations data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the follwing problem, I have two models, Level and Class, each level has many classes inside it, I need to add all level classes at once , with the follwing format:

```
$levelclasses['0'][level_id]=1;
$levelclasses['0'][class][0][supervisor_id]=2;
$levelclasses['1'][level_id]=2;
$levelclasses['1'][class][0][supervisor_id]=2;
```

I added this successfully :

```
    $levelNewClasses;
    $ids;
    $count=0;

    foreach ($data['levelclasses'] as $levelClass) {
        $level=\App\InstituteLevel::find($levelClass['level_id']);
        $ids[$count]=$level->id;
        $count++; 
        foreach ($levelClass['class'] as $classdata) {
             $class= new \App\EClass($classdata);
             $class->school_year_id=\App\SchoolsYear::first()->id;
             $level->classes()->save($class);
             $levelNewClasses[$level->id][$class->id]=$class->id;
        }
    }
```

but now I want to return with the response just the inserted classes, not all classes , if I do this :

```
$level->classes;
```

it will return all , so I stored the new classes id's in an array and now I try to filter the classes returned from this relation $level->classes based on theses id's, I tried this

```
foreach ($levels as $level){

        $levelclasses=$level->classes->pluck('id');

        $level->classes=$levelclasses->intersect($levelNewClasses[$level->id]);
    }
```

but this doesn't work ! , Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by **inserted classes** ? Could you add the code where you are inserting the class.

Comment: I added the code, I mean by inserted classes , are just the classes that created with this request, when I access the relation it returns all classes.

Comment: If you want to return the inserted classes, why don't you just return the classes received from the request. In this case your `$levelClass['class']` variable.

Comment: this doesn't work in my case since i want  to return the id's of created classes with the response, but I'm wondering if there is a way to change the data of the relation it self for example delete some records from it after retrieving it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following code. I think it would work.

```
    $levelNewClasses;
    $ids;
    $count=0;
    insertedClasses = array();//Array to store inserted classes
    foreach ($data['levelclasses'] as $levelIndex=>$levelClass) {\\updated to include level index
        $level=\App\InstituteLevel::find($levelClass['level_id']);
        $ids[$count]=$level->id;
        $count++; 
        foreach ($levelClass['class'] as $index=>$classdata) {
             $class= new \App\EClass($classdata);
             $class->school_year_id=\App\SchoolsYear::first()->id;
//Use following code to get all the inserted classes as array 
             $insertedClasses[$levelIndex][$index] = $level->classes()->save($class)->toArray();\\updated to use 2d array to store both level and class
             $levelNewClasses[$level->id][$class->id]=$class->id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code return just the last class added, in my response I want to return each level with all inserted classes inserted to it.

Comment: @محمود عبد الكريم  updated the code to include level index. check it once

Comment: You saved my day brother , you inspire me to solve this problem thanks a lot  .

Comment: Glad that I could help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hacky way to do it, but if your model has the `created_at` or `updated_at` timestamps (which Eloquent models do by default), you could see if it was created or updated in the last few seconds. For instance, to see if it was created in the last 10 seconds:

```
foreach($level->classes as $class) {
  if($class->created_at->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now()) < 10) {
    // do something...
  }       
}
```

In order to do this, you need to import [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Put `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the top of your class to do this.

Essentially, what the above code is doing is figuring out when each of the level's classes were created, comparing it in seconds to the current time, and entering that `if` statement if the class was created less than 10 seconds before the current time (`Carbon::now()`). Obviously, you don't necessarily have to do 10 seconds - find which time works best for you.

As I said, this is a bit of a hack, and may not work for all cases, but I think it will work for the case you're describing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Man for your help, you are very welcome, as you said this doesn't work in all cases, but I'm wondering if there is a way to change the data of the relation it self for example delete some records from it after retrieving it ?